# How to generate application version using Spring Boot, Gradle, Semantic Versioning and Jenkins

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, semantic-versioning, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a Spring Boot web application with actuator enabled. When I open `<app_url>/info`, I see below

```
{
    "git": {
        "commit": {
            "time": "2016-08-31T17:53:28.000+0000",
            "id": "0a52a2f"
        },
        "branch": "master"
    },
    "build": {
        "version": "unspecified",
        "artifact": "my-app",
        "name": "my-app",
        "group": "",
        "time": "2016-09-02T21:09:42.000+0000"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to generate a version number here. I want to use Semantic Versioning `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH+timestamp+Build_Number`

What is the general consensus w.r.t storing build information of a package ? I don't want to store it in `application.yml` because it is managed by Puppet and is external to the application war. I would like it to be generated by Jenkins into some file and Spring Boot can pick it up from that file. Should I let Jenkins write into `build-info.properties` that is generated by `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` `buildInfo` ? or should the version be generated by Gradle itself when it generates the file? How does Gradle know `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH` details ? I'm running out of ideas on how to integrate all these together.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but this is how I am doing it (seems to work).

```
springBoot  {
    buildInfo {
        additionalProperties = [
            "version" : System.properties["version"] != null ? System.properties["version"] : "unspecified"
        ]
    }
}
```

and then in my Jenkins Pipeline

```
./gradlew clean build -Dversion=${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}
```

The output jar then will have a build-info.properties

```
build.version=1.0.1
```

Comment: And idea how you would translate this to a `build.gradle.kts` file? The springBoot part for example is as follows: `configure<org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension> { buildInfo() }`.